# Reorder div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the order of the `div`s using JavaScript`. Is this how I can go about it?

```
<div id="pageWrapper">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="four">4</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#pageWrapper').prepend('#three');
        $('#pageWrapper').prepend('#four');

});
```

Comment: Well does it work? Have you tried running the code?

Comment: You should consider using CSS flexbox to achieve this instead.

Comment: why would i get a -1 this is a pretty straight forward question, how do I prepend one div so it moves from where it is to the first child of page wrapper?

Comment: @user3117555 - It doesn't work because `prepend` accept a node or an jQuery object instead of a String: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eHq2a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this with the `window.resize()` event if needed (you'd use an else statement to set it back to default as well)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){    
     if ($(window).width() < 980) {
        $('#three').insertBefore('#one');
        $('#four').insertBefore('#two');
     } else {
      // Set back to default, or whatever you like.
     }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9EKja/)**

Comment: This will work, though prependTo is probably a more logical method to use. https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Answer (score 1):

`prepend` does not accept a String selector. From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

> [`.prepend( content [,content] )`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/#prepend-content-content)
>   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>   **content**
>   Type: [`htmlString`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) or [`Element`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element) or [`Array`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Array) or [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)
>
> DOM element, array of elements, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

You have to pass a jQuery object instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eHq2a/

```
$('#pageWrapper').prepend($('#three'));
$('#pageWrapper').prepend($('#four'));

//or just

$('#pageWrapper').prepend($('#four'), $('#three'));
```

However, interestingly [`.prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) does accept a String selector:

```
$("#three").prependTo("#pageWrapper");
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use some responsive design then. In your case, use @media queries in CSS. Way better than doing it in script.

```
@media screen and (max-width:980px) {
/* your style */
}
```

If you still prefer to use script, then you can subscribe to the resize event handler like

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width()<requiredMinimum)
  {
    //dowhatever
  }
  else
  {
    //revertback
  }
});
```

Comment: Good advice but ... how does this answer the question?